# Send a string array to a function by pointer or pointer-to-pointer with mem alloc?

Tags: c, function, pointers, pass-by-reference

Both of these functions fill the TCHAR sStringA and sStringB. The question is which one is preferred and more efficient in returning a result?

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void FunctionA(TCHAR *sString1, DWORD dwLen)
{
_tcscpy_s(sString1, dwLen, L"String1");

return;
}

void FunctionB(TCHAR **sString2, DWORD dwLen)
{
*sString2 = (TCHAR*)calloc(dwLen, sizeof(TCHAR));
_tcscpy_s(*sString2, dwLen, L"String2");

return;
}

int main()
{
TCHAR *sStringA = (TCHAR*)calloc(100, sizeof(TCHAR));
TCHAR *sStringB = NULL;

FunctionA(sStringA, 100);
FunctionB(&sStringB, 100);

free(sStringA);
free(sStringB);
}
```

From my comment below, here is FunctionC:

```
void FunctionC(TCHAR **sString2, DWORD dwLenOut)
{
    TCHAR sString[] = L"String2";
    dwLenOut = (DWORD) _tcslen(sString) + 1;
    *sString2 = (TCHAR*)calloc(dwLenOut, sizeof(TCHAR));
    _tcscpy_s(*sString2, dwLenOut, sString);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    TCHAR *sStringC = NULL;
    DWORD dwLen = 0;
    FunctionC(&sStringC, dwLen);
}
```

Comment: The big time consumer here is the calloc, not the call FunctionA/B itself.

Comment: What were your result when you benchmarked and profiled the code?

Comment: Another possibility is `TCHAR *FunctionD(DWORD dwLen)` called by `TCHAR *sStringD = FunctionD(100)` which does less dereferencing and argument pushing. I could not reliably find any one to be faster than any other, and the difference is minute compared to the `calloc` requirement.

Answer (score 3):

It is highly unlikely to be any more costly to pass a pointer to a pointer than it is to pass a pointer to a `TCHAR`.  The only significant difference between your two alternatives, performance-wise, is that B performs one extra address-of (`&`) and one dereference (unary `*`) operation, and although that makes B a tiny bit more costly in principle, the difference is unlikely to be noticeable.

Of course, the compiler could optimize the two calls to exactly the same code.  It might even optimize away the `calloc()` calls, though that's less likely.

Overall, it is unlikely to be worth your time to focus on micro-optimizations of this sort, unless possibly you've determined, by measurement, that the section of code containing them is too slow, and you cannot find an *algorithmic* improvement, and you've reason to believe that the specific operations you're trying to optimize make a significant contribution to that code's cost.

Comment: I just don't want to pass an entire character string to the function. Also, I created FunctionC above, which always has dwLen as 0?

Comment: @JeffR, you are not passing a character string -- an array -- to any of the function.  You *can't* -- C has no mechanism by which you could do so.  In particular, your call to `FunctionA()` passes a *pointer*.

Comment: @JeffR, as for your `FunctionC`, it does not use the passed-in value of its second parameter, so that value is irrelevant.  That function is somewhat more costly because of its `_tcslen()` call, but you could rewrite to avoid a need for that, or the compiler might optimize it out.  In any case, if that way you manage to allocate less memory then that version makes more efficient use of memory, but there's no reason to expect it to run faster than the others.

Answer (score 0):

`FunctionA` is **slightly** is more efficient, because it does less dereferencing.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler inline them?

Comment: Using VS 2017. Options are Default, Disable, Only Inline, Any Suitable. "Default" is the default option.